# How do you make a new FlatButtonAppearance object?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm running into a frustratingly stupid problem with the [`FlatButtonAppearance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flatbuttonappearance?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) object, which apparently has a constructor that I can't find any information about.

It doesn't seem to have any defined constructors, and doesn't inherit from anything - I was under the impression that the compiler would generate a blank constructor `public FlatButtonAppearance() {}`, however that doesn't appear to be the case.

Whenever I try creating a `FlatButtonAppearance` object using any of the following methods:

```cs
FlatButtonAppearance flatAppearance = new();
```

```cs
FlatButtonAppearance flatAppearance = new()
{
    BorderSize = 1,
    BorderColor = Color.Transparent,
    CheckedBackColor = Color.Transparent,
    MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent,
    MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent
};
```

It throws this error:

```
error CS1729: 'FlatButtonAppearance' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

So clearly it *does* have a constructor, however neither intellisense nor MSDN will tell me what its signature is.
Even Visual Studio's metadata doesn't show a constructor.

The only way that I can find that actually works is this:

```cs
FlatAppearance flatAppearance = new Button().FlatAppearance;
```

but `Button` has to get that from somewhere too, and creating an entire button control just so I can use the `FlatAppearance` property is just a dirty hack.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: The constructor is `internal`, see [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/FlatButtonAppearance.cs)

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot!

Is there some other way to go about this? Or am I just out of luck?

Comment: It's not useful as a standalone object, what are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: My end goal is to provide a default appearance for buttons that I'm using as dynamic tab headers for a `TabControl`-style control I'm making from scratch.

Comment: When you have a specialized Control, which has specific destination, building a Custom Control is standard procedure. I have no idea why you consider a Custom Control a *dirty hack*.

Comment: The dirty hack was making a button object and immediately discarding it: `new Button().FlatAppearance`, not making a custom control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your response comment, you could do something like this:

```
public abstract class TabHeaderButtonBase : ButtonBase
{
    public TabHeaderButtonBase() : base()
    {
        /* You'll probably want this as well... */
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;

        FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
        FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = Color.Transparent;
        FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
        FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;

        /* And any other defaults... */
    }
}
```

Then use this type as the base for your custom buttons.